# Vim close buffer with nerdtree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

My current use case is:
I have a buffer open with a NERDTree (Left) and 1 with a file being edited (Right)

Lets also assume 2 other files in background buffers are open as well.

[image]

If i press c (shortcut for closing buffer, basically :bd), the Right side is gone and only the left side is displayed. But when closing a buffer, i would expect that vim will close the current file buffer and keep the right side to open one of the buffers that are in the background.

[image]

How do I achieve the expected behavior?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use

```
nnoremap c :bp\|bd #<CR>
```

Which will first go to the previous buffer, then delete the last buffer. This way it will both close the buffer and go to the previous one.

Answer (score 4):

May be [bufkill](https://github.com/qpkorr/vim-bufkill) can solve this issue for you.